# Custom subdomain with a SSL not redirecting to Azure cloudapp

Tags: ssl, azure, subdomain, cname, azure-deployment

I have an Azure app deployed and I want to use SSL for the entire application.

To do secure my app:

```
-I made a subdomain in my site to point to the Azure application.
-I got a SSL in the name of my subdomain
-Add the certificate to the applicaton
-Loaded the certificate to the Azure hosted account
-Opened up a https endpoint in the application.
```

Now this is where the problem comes up. When I enter in my url (with the subdomain) the page can not be found. However, if I manually enter in https:// in the url it will go to the site as it should.

What is going on here? I have only a https endpoint open. Do I need a http endpoint to? If I do, I can't let the user use the app without an encryption, so how would I solve that?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is not a specific Azure problem.  When typing in URL w/o the https://, browsers automatically assume the http:// protocol and pre-pend it.  Since you did not open the http endpoint, you're getting error when connecting.

Suggestion: open the http endpoint.  Redirect/rewrite the URL to https upon the connection to the http endpoint.  How to do this, depends on the technology you're using to develop your site in.  (ASP.NET, MVC, etc)

Comment: I am developing in MVC. How would I switch traffic from the http endpoint to the https endpoit?

Comment: Check out this Stackoverflow question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072814/net-mvc-rewrite-urls-certain-urls-through-ssl  You may want to to create a custom Attribute  or used standard RequireHttps and assign it to any controller that you wish to redirect through SSL